# Need to check for existing button and add new button below it (not a command button)

Tags: excel, vba, button

I have the following code working where a user inputs the name of a delivery route and then a worksheet and button is created for the route. They can then click the button and it will take them to the appropriate route worksheet where they can enter invoice numbers. I need to set this up so additional routes can be added. Right now, the existing button gets overridden by the new button. What I need is to have a new button for the new route added below the existing button. To make matters worse, this needs to be used at multiple sites with varying amounts of routes. So, I need the sheet to have the ability for a user to add additional routes (which would result in additional buttons being added) and if they get to 8 buttons in one column, I want it to start another column to the right of the first column of buttons. I'm struggling to figure out a good way to do this. I would greatly appreciate any guidance. Thank you. Here is the code I'm using so far:

```
    Sub AddRoute()
    Dim btn As Button
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim t As Range
    Dim sName As String
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Worksheets("NewRoute").Copy after:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    Do While sName <> wks.Name
        sName = Application.InputBox _
          (Prompt:="Enter new route name")
        On Error Resume Next
        wks.Name = sName
        Worksheets("Home").Activate
        On Error GoTo 0

        Set t = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, 12), Cells(3, 13))
        Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)


    With btn
      .OnAction = "'btnS""" & sName & """'"
      .Caption = sName
      .Name = sName
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Loop
    Set wks = Nothing

End Sub



Sub btnS(sName)
  Worksheets(sName).Activate
    Range("A:A").Find("").Select
```

End Sub

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you post a screenshot diagram what you have currently and what you would like to end up with. It will help us help you better (than the text you have written).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is you're referencing same range "t" all times you run the macro. You should to declare two variable int and initialize it with 2 and 3 and add 2 for these two int variables at the end of the loop.

For example:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

i = 2
j = 3

Do While sName <> wks.Name

    sName = Application.InputBox _
        (Prompt:="Enter new route name")
    On Error Resume Next
    wks.Name = sName
    Worksheets("Home").Activate
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set t = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, 12), Cells(j, 13))
    Set btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)


    With btn
        .OnAction = "'btnS""" & sName & """'"
        .Caption = sName
        .Name = sName
    End With

    i = i + 2
    j = j + 2

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Loop
```

Comment: This helped tremendously! Thank you very much!